# Hacer una búsqueda de una palabra que no existe en visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, visual, busqueda, buscador

Tengo un proyecto con más de 100 archivos y quiero buscar los archivos que no contengan dentro del código la palabra hola, he probado con la búsqueda de expresiones regulares pero sin éxito, ¿alguna idea de como hacer esto en visual studio?

Comment: Esto capaz te sirva: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58491613/11539923)